# iFrame on portfolio site is not as wide as it is supposed to be

Tags: html, css, web, youtube

I have a website I am trying to link youtube videos on.  When I test the site in chrome it looks fine, but when I upload my files and view the site online, I get what you see in the picture.  Tried to include the code.

[Skinny Youtube Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YopIt.jpg)

Comment: Hello, I see you're a new user, please post the relevant CSS and HTML code of the iframe (including the containers they're in) in form of text so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gunther said, since you have not provided any code, it will be hard to help you. Looking at the image, I see you added an height attribute to the iframe, but no width attribute, which is your problem. To fix this, you just add this to your iframe:

`width="600"`

Now if you want to change the width, just change the value above.

Example of usage of width attribute:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Hope this helps read more at: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_width.asp